# How to set non changeable option?

Tags: vimrc

I installed the cool plugin ("thaerkh/vim-workspace") that make autosession and autosave. But I noticed that when I enter into vim again after quit, some options are rewritable. For example `set noshowmode` and I see mode in status line twice, cuz I use the airline status plugin.

How can I set this option permanent?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure I follow your question. You use airline, so the mode is the airline statusline, correct? That's separate from the `showmode` option, which uses a little "messages/command-line" area.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think the OP means he wants to always have `noshowmode` because airline makes it redundant, but he seems not to be able to 'save' the setting.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to have an option always applied is to put it in your vim config file (which is most probably your `vimrc`).

Drop `set noshowmode` in your vimrc and it should be done.

By default, though, settings are saved with your sessions.
This behavior is dictated by the `'sessionoptions'` option.

Your plugin may deactivate this, I'm not familiar with it though. If you wanted to not save options with the session, set `sessionoptions-=options` in your vimrc, or `sessionoptions+=options` for the opposite behavior (the default).

I just wanted to point this because your plugin seems to interfere with it, which seems to confuse you.